# jest to ignore node_modules subdirectory when moving to report coverage

Tags: jestjs

I'm new to jest and am having trouble getting it to ignore select directories where I run it. How do I get jest to not process content from the node_modules subdirectory?

I've tried to set up package.json with every ignore option I could find as shown below (Note: I also tried with  preceding the leading / like /node_modules) but it still seems to want to parse node_modules content:

```
   "scripts": {
      "test": "jest --watch",
      "coverage": "jest --coverage"
   },
   "jest": {
      "automock": false,
      "verbose": false,
      "collectCoverageFrom": [
         "/routes/*.{js}"
      ],
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
         "/public/",
         "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
         "/public/",
         "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
         "/public/",
         "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
         "/public/",
         "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": [
         "/public/",
         "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "testEnvironment": "node"
   },
```

and my test passes, but then I get an error due to a module in the node_modules directory:

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.187 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites.

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From __tests__/Test.js.

      at BufferList.Readable (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:179:22)
      at BufferList.Duplex (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
      at new BufferList (node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
      at new MessageStream (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
      at new Connection (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:54:28)
/Users/wnm3/csnext/common/UXServer/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:111
  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex;
                        ^
```

Comment: Please give a [mre], it seems like the problem is in your testing of asynchronous code rather than Jest's ignoring of any given directory.

Comment: No, my test completed as shown. then Jest is reading into the node_modules directory and getting tripped up when it shouldn't be reading the directory at all given all of the ignore statements I've attempted to configure. I suspect when it is preparing to do the coverage report it has gone into node_modules for some reason and hit the error it is reporting.

Comment: The tests may appear to pass because the expectations are asynchronous and not correctly handled, so they're never reached during the execution of the tests. It's reporting an import in _your_ code (test or implementation) not the framework (which _is_ allowed to import stuff for e.g. reporting after it's finished running the tests). But without a MRE, we can only speculate.

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe -- I'd been thrown by the "Tests: 1 passed, 1 total" and the "Ran all test suites." along with the console.log output I'd seeded throughout my code showing up, and some reference to a node_module that was not at all related to the real problem. Indeed it was how I'd set up the request that was failing to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'd followed some examples that showed passing an exported app to the supertest but found I needed to export a variable set to the server.listen... and use the agent from supertest to create my Test with a request as follows:

```
const {agent} = require("supertest");
const {httpServer} = require("../UXServer");
const request = agent(httpServer);

afterAll(done => {
   httpServer.close(done);
});

describe("Test example", () => {
   it("GET /someroute", async () => {
      const res = await request.get("/UXServer/someroute");
      expect(res.body.routedetails).not.toBe(null);
      console.log(res.body);
   });
});
```

In the UXServer the code was like below after setting up the app as normal:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(app);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/UXServer', UXServerRoute.router);
const httpServer = server.listen(port, () => { /* stubbed out */ });

module.exports = { httpServer }; // there were other exports for testing
```

and the UXServerRoute's router that was exported had:

```
router.get('/someroute', function(req, res) {
   res.status(200).json({
        'routedetails': {
          'clipboardOnCopy': false,
          'copyContentToAgent': true,
          'assistMasking': false,
          'responses': [ ]
        }
      });
});
```

Following [this article](https://dev.to/mhmdlotfy96/testing-nodejs-express-api-with-jest-and-supertest-1bk0) helped me realize how to set up the request properly.

Comment: Note that a better structure, as used by the [Express Generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), is to _separate_ the app from the server - "other exports for testing" is a smell, you should be able to just import the same Express app object the same way the server (`bin/www` in the above) would, and pass it to SuperTest or its agent.